# Django (South): change model application

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have defined some models within an application, call it "blog".

```
djangoproject
    /blog
        models.py
```

I now want to change the models location, for example put them here:

```
djangoproject
    /blog
        xxx
    /all_models
        models.py
```

From the code point of view, this is pretty trivial, but the I guess there will be problems on the database since all the tables Django and South created are now called `blog_posts` `blog_comments`, Django relies on this naming convention and I don't want to lose the data already present in the database.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing is not to bother changing the tables at all, but the code. Inside the `Meta` class of each of your models, put the declaration `db_table = "blog_tablename"`, and Django will find them without problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in two ways.
The first and easier one is to provide a db_table in Meta class of each of your models. The other is create a migration to apply the change.

As far as I know south doesn't support table rename, so you should do it as a three way migration:

- Move de models, and create migration (now you have both tables old and new)
- Create a data migration and iterate over the former table, copying objects to later
- Remove the former model, and create a migration for it.

You can read a little bit more about the second way [in south docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations)